# DC Block/high pass filter

Tags: rf, filter, antenna

I'm looking to design a DC blocking capacitor for an eternal antenna, to ensure no DC voltage can pass to the antenna.

Is this the correct way to simulate it, with the probe between the capacitor and resistor?

Thanks

[image]

https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjOB0CcCsDMYBMsCmBaMEBskAssADMdPIdngByywDslIRjjhjGWAUAMYhJ6thsrfgKEhW8SPHYRCkMLThEFheHFqFq8cZGJgOAJxAjwYk0koNWRDgHljxU9eRPx4jgHMHrCwxPwkViCOACVefldAhkEg8CdiBMdYNyDIWA4Ae15TN35oaNTE6FpsWGwUNwgMgFcAFw4ACxBtWQ4gA

Comment: "*for an eternal antenna*" -- amen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to *simulate* it (by probing the voltage between OUT and ground), but this is not the correct way to actually implement such a circuit for signal integrity and impedance matching, assuming a 50-ohm antenna.

An output that expects a 50-ohm impedance would see a reflection from the antenna in parallel with the 50-ohm biasing resistor, which would result in wasted energy or could even lead to oscillation and amplifier damage.

If your source is a pure voltage source, then you can use series termination and a bias tee that doesn't resistively load the line:

[image]

On the other hand, if your signal generator were an *ideal* *current* source, then you could use this kind of resistive parallel termination if you wanted to; in that case the terminating resistor should be physically close to the source.